# Can an identical profile and theme name cause conflict during installation?

Tags: theming, distributions

I recently purchased a theme to install it on an Aegir hosting environment, which is a multi-site installation system. Does identical profile and theme names cause conflict or errors in Drupal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Modules, themes, and profiles must have unique names.